Application Insights with DefaultAzureCredentials in node js application using Azure user authentication
I was trying to do Application Insights with DefaultAzureCredentials in my node js application using @azure/identity and applicationinsights here is my peace of code


const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require('@azure/identity');
const appInsights = require("applicationinsights");
 appInsights.setup(process.env.APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING || config.applicationInsights.connectionString)
  .setAutoCollectConsole(true)
  .setSendLiveMetrics(true)
  .start();
  const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
  const client = appInsights.defaultClient;
  client.config.aadTokenCredential = credential;
  client.trackEvent({ name: 'testEvent', properties: { customProperty: 'customValue' } });



I Have configured environment variables correctly to use DefaultAzureCredential
$env:AZURE_CLIENT_ID="XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXX"
$env:AZURE_TENANT_ID="XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXX"
$env:AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET="XXXXXXXXXXXX"
Im Capturing the const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(); its look like


DefaultAzureCredential {
  _sources: [
    EnvironmentCredential { _credential: [ClientSecretCredential] },
    UnavailableDefaultCredential {  
credentialName: 'createDefaultWorkloadIdentityCredential',
      credentialUnavailableErrorMessage: 'WorkloadIdentityCredential: is unavailable. federatedTokenFilePath is a required parameter. In DefaultAzureCredential and ManagedIdentityCredential, this can be provided as an environment variable - "AZURE_FEDERATED_TOKEN_FILE".\n' +
        '        See the troubleshooting guide for more information: https://aka.ms/azsdk/js/identity/workloadidentitycredential/troubleshoot'
    },
    ManagedIdentityCredential { implProvider: [MsalMsiProvider] },
    AzureCliCredential {
      additionallyAllowedTenantIds: [],
      timeout: undefined
    },
    AzurePowerShellCredential {
      additionallyAllowedTenantIds: [],
      timeout: undefined
    },
    AzureDeveloperCliCredential {
      additionallyAllowedTenantIds: [],
      timeout: undefined
    }
  ]
}



And Given the role based access in azure application insight but I can't logs and failures not showing application insights logs.

Are you getting any error in local?

Initially i got 'EnvironmentCredential authentication failed. To troubleshoot, visit
https://aka.ms/azsdk/js/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot.'
this error after set $env:AZURE_CLIENT_ID="XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXX" $env:AZURE_TENANT_ID="XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXX" $env:AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET="XXXXXXXXXXXX" i didn't get any error but in application insights no logs created. In azure application insights given the user lever access permission also.

How you are configuring your ApplicationInsights?Are you able to log traces without authentication ? check once

@Raghu Please give Monitoring Metrics Publisher role in your application insights, I can see the traces.

The issue you're facing missing traces and telemetry data in Application Insights may be related to the role assignments for your Azure AD application.

As you mentioned that you provided user-level access permissions, this might prevent the application from sending telemetry data.
To fix this , change the Azure AD application's role to Monitoring Metrics Publisherfor Application Insights. This will let your application send telemetry data without needing individual user permissions.
Refer this doc for better understanding about Azure built-in roles for monitor.
Go to Azure portal - > your application insight resource -> Access control (IAM) - > click Add role assignment -> select Monitoring Metrics Publisher -> choose the assign access to user,group,service principal or managed identity -> select members and hit Review+Assign.




By adding the above role, I can see the traces in my application insights.

